# Flag column values that are not present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

I have a benchmark df_1:

```
Col_1   insight_id    Col_2    Col_n
24249       ABC123      656      AAA
24249       ABC123      670      AXA
22549       ABC124      656      AAC
24249       ABC124      656      ADA
24236       ABC125      656      AAA
```

And a dataset df_2:

```
Col_a   insight_id    Col_b    Col_x
24299       ABC123      956      XAA
24299       ABC123      970      AXX
24299       ABC125      954      AAX
24299       ABC125      956      AXX
```

How do I mark the `insight_id`s that are not present in the second dataset? I know about:

```
df_1.loc[df_1['insight_id'].isin(df_2['insight_id'])]
```

But it doesn't lead to my expected output, which, in this case is:

```
insight_id
    ABC124
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negate the condition:

```py
cond = df_1["insight_id"].isin(df_2["insight_id"])
df_1.loc[~cond, "insight_id"].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: A one-liner: `df_new = df1[~df1.insight_id.isin(df2.insight_id)].insight_id.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: I knew about the one-line but I chose not to use it. Breaking it over 2 lines is a lot more readable to me.